# 'str' object has no attribute biopython

Tags: string, atributos

Estou trabalhando com o biopython. 
Peço a entrada de um input():

```
enz_name1 = input('ENZYME 1 NAME: ')
enz_name2 = input('ENZYME 2 NAME: ')
```

Porém, quando quero utilizar o input() para usar na opção .catalyse, dessa forma:

```
    rb=RestrictionBatch()
    rb.add(enz_name1)
    rb.add(enz_name2)
    #enz_name=enz#  
print(rb.catalyse(my_seq,linear=False))
```

or even:

```
print (enz_name1.catalyse(my_seq, linear=False)
```

Eu tenho o erro 'str' object has no attribute.
E se eu usar o nome da enzima normal (ex. EcoRI or XmaI) funciona, mas não a string que eu obtenho como input. Há uma forma de converter essas strings na forma não string dessas enzimas que são reconhecidas pela opção .catalyse?

Comment: `enz_name1` é uma string logo não temnenhum método `catalyse`. Isso provavelmente deve vir de outro objeto de alguma classe que está a utilizar e você está a fazer confusão entre os objetos. Só com o código que colocou aqui não é possivel de saber o que estava a tentar fazer.

Comment: Acho que você quer a função `search()`. Um objeto do tipo `RestrictionBatch()` não tem a função `catalyse()`.